# Trigonometric factorisation

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to factor the following formula:

$2+cos(2x)$.

It looks trivial, but I did not find any way to express it as a product of trigonometry (or other) functions.

Any idea how I could move forward?

Comment: It is not in any natural way a product of two functions.  What makes you think it is?

Comment: I am not sure to understand ‘natural way’ and I am not limited to two functions only. I am looking for a result such as 1+cos(2x)=2cos(x)cos(x). I don’t know if it exists. It would help me move forward in my development.

Comment: @Christophe "*Move forward*" towards what? It's hard to guess what you are looking  for if you don't explain what the purpose it. For example, you could write it as $\,3 \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x\,$ and factor the difference of squares, but no one knows if that's useful or not for whatever it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the addition formula : $\ \cos(a)+\cos(b)=2\cos(\frac{a+b}2)\cos(\frac{a-b}2)$

All you need here is to calculate the angle $y$ such that $\cos(y)=\frac 12\cos(2x)$ which is possible since the RHS still belongs to $[-1,1]$.

This way you can reduce the expression to $2\Big(\cos(0)+\cos(y)\Big)=4\cos(\frac y2)^2$

The drawback is that even if the expression is factorized and in appearance simpler, you have introduced an $\arccos$ (into $y$) which itself is more complicated.

Comment: Could you explain why an arccos has been introduced into y? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this represents the problem composer's intent.

$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$.

Therefore,

$$2 + \cos(2x) = 3 - 2\sin^2(x) = \left[\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}\sin(x)\right]  \times \left[\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}\sin(x)\right].$$